# Adding source code Nodeclipse

Tags: eclipse, node.js, express, nodeclipse

I am experimenting Node.js with Express. I am using Nodeclipse plugin for Eclipse.
Can any one please suggest me how to add/link source code of Express (generally any third party module) to the project in eclipse?

Comment: Isn't Express written in JavaScript and you already should have those unminified files?

Comment: raise deatiled issue at https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/